# Cloud foundry push from URL

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

There is option to push the application **from git URL or any URL**
using the CF Client (I mean via code)  ?

Here there is documentation how to push from path
http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/push.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the cf CLI, nor the Java client, nor the Cloud Controller API currently accept a git URL (or any other URL) to download the application bits into Cloud Foundry.
The `--path` option on `cf push` only accepts paths on your local filesystem.

If we were to support this (the topic has come up once or twice), it may make most sense for the Cloud Controller to expose an API for it, so that it can be supported by all CF clients in the same way. With this approach, CF can also be smarter about updates: it can check the git sha to know whether new bits need to be downloaded.

An issue with the current APIs for the CLI is that the CLI would first need to download the app bits from the URL and then upload it to CF, which seems inefficient. It would not be any faster than `git clone https://github.com/example/app && cf push myapp -p app` (apart from saving you a handful of keystrokes).

Comment: Thanks for the detail and prompt first-hand response, really nice to you here!

Comment: @AnatolyKern Thanks for sharing that link to the CF projects, I didn't know that was up yet!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware cf client does not support direct deployment via code relying on CI/CD systems for this.

Some helpful links for research and discuss it:

Project manager/lead for CF CLI project - Dies Köper 
( https://www.cloudfoundry.org/projects/ -> CLI )

#cli on cloudfoundry.slack.com

Tracker on https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/892938